# trema (ddot) does not appear in mathrm mode with newtxmath font

Tags: fonts, math-operators, accents, newtxmath, newtx

Apologies for such a specific question. I am using the newtx fonts. For some reason, it seems that newtxmath ignores the trema (ddot) in math mode when using `\operatorname` or even just `\mathrm`. Here is a sample document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{\ddot{o}}$
$\operatorname{M\ddot{o}bius}$
\end{document}
```

This produces:

> o
>   Mobius

instead of the desired

> ö
>   Möbius

As an alternative, I could instead use `\textup{M\"{o}b}` which works. But I'm sure there is a reason `\operatorname` is preferable to `\textup`, although I'm not expert enough to understand it.

Comment: By the way, `\ddot{\mathrm{o}}` inserts double dots over `o`.

Comment: In the case of "Möbius", ,that's strictly speaking an _umlaut_, not a trema, since it doesn't serve to change what would otherwise be a diphthong.

Comment: @phipsgabler I was told by my German teacher that trema refers to the sign, while umlaut refers to the sound change. Maybe she was wrong.

Comment: Hm, a valid point from a typographic perspective. On the other hand, we practically never refer to the dots themselves, since the whole letter is considered a separate grapheme, distinct from <o>, and not as an <o> with diacritics. And it is either pronounced as "Umlaut-O", "Umlaut-Ö", or simply [øː], never as "O with dots", as in other languages. (The usage of "trema" exclusively for diphthong separation might just be a personal bias from my knowledge about classical Greek, though...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mobius}{M\mathnormal{\ddot{\mathrm{o}}}bius}

\begin{document}

$\mobius$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With the default setup you need to use the text accents not math so `\textrm{Möbius}`  but `\operatorname` gives "log-like" prefix operator spacing, so to get the effect of that, wrap in the primitive `\mathop` command, so

```
\mathop{\textrm{Möbius}}
```